# How to extend the response of an api in react by adding a new property based on a condition?

Tags: javascript

I want to call an API and extend the response by adding a  new 'category' prop to each
categories ['thirds', 'fifths', 'magic']

- if the id is divisible by 3 => thirds
- if the id is divisible by 5 => fifths
- if the id is divisibly by 3 and 5 => magic

The url is https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

How do i do that?

```
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    const data = await response.json();
  }

{contacts.map((contact) => (
             {contact.id}
              {contact.userId}
            {contact.title}
              {contact.body}
           
            ))}
```

Comment: `contacts.map` is a good start, but the random braces aren't helping at all. This is a pure JS problem, take React out of it - you want a map over an array of objects that returns a new array of objects with an additional property.

Comment: You can create a shallow copy like this: `const copy = { ...post };` Now you can do `if (copy.id % 3 === 0) copy.prop = "thirds";` then `return copy;` inside your map() callback.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number (`x`) is divisible by a number (`N`) we use a modulo operator (`%`), which returns the rest of a division, so eg. if `x=5` and `N=2` then `x%N=1`, because `5%2=1` (`5/2=2+1`).

So in your case you indeed can use a `map` function and add a property to your object conditionally, based on the result of according modulo operation result:

```
contacts.map(contact => {
   return {
      ...contact,
      ...((contact.id%3===0 && contact.id%5!=0) &&
          {category: 'thirds'}),
      ...((contact.id%3!=0 && contact.id%5===0) &&
          {category: 'fifths'}),
      ...((contact.id%3===0 && contact.id%5===0) &&
          {category: 'magic'})
   };
});
```